# is dispatch_semaphore_t thread safe

Tags: ios, multithreading, grand-central-dispatch

The semaphore I talk about is init this way

> dispatch_semaphore_t signal = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);

So can this signal variable be `dispatch_semaphore_wait` and `dispatch_semaphore_signal` from different threads or queues directly.

Note: I do find the doc said "Dispatch queues themselves are thread safe." in [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationQueues/OperationQueues.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH102-SW24). But cannot find anything about dispatch_semaphore_t

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It has to be thread safe otherwise there would be no point.

The only way to use a semaphore is to call `dispatch_semaphore_wait` on one thread and `dispatch_semaphore_signal` on another thread. It's impossible to call both from the same thread (OK, it's possible but it would be pointless and non-functional).